# Django 1.5.1 - Admin.py missing while running startapp

Tags: django

I've been following the DjangoProject tutorial. When I run python manage.py startapp newapp while in the same directory as manage.py. In the newapp directory I see init.py, models.py, tests.py, and views.py but not admin.py file. Where is admin.py?

I am running Django 1.5.1 in Windows 8

Comment: why was this downvoted?  i just had the same question.

Answer (score 2):

You have to **create** an `admin.py` file.

Comment: I have uncommented all relevant lines in the Setting file

Answer (score 0):

you don't necessarily need an admin.py file,

just import the admin module in your models.py file,

```
from django.contrib import admin
```

and for each model do the following:

```
admin.site.register(model1)
admin.site.register(model2)
```

However, this is not best practice, but since it's just a tutorial, it will work.

You also need to uncoment the relevant lines in the urls.py file

Answer (score 0):

I think I had the same frustrations following the DjangoProject tutorial - however, when I cross-referenced it with with the DjangoBook tutorial (for the same version, I believe, 1.5.1), I found that an `admin.py` file was not necessarily created after a `python manage.py startapp xyz` command -- moreover, I also uncommented all of the admin options in `urls.py`, `views.py`, and `settings.py` - so a bit of a mix of what Neal and Ibrahim said

Answer (score 0):

You have to create your own admin.py file in the app if you want it. Indeed, this file is optionnal and isn't created by startapp.

If you want a default template to begin your admin.py, it should be:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from models import Model1, Model2

class Model2Admin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display   = ('title', 'content', 'date')
    # Just an example, chekc docs and tutorials for more info.

admin.site.register(Model1)
admin.site.register(Model2, Model2Admin)
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason there is no default `admin.py` is because you don't have any models yet when you create your new application; so there is nothing to add to the admin section.

Further, you may not want to admin all the models in your application; or you may be creating an application that does not need any admin hookups; or you may not be using the admin application at all in your project.

Since django cannot decide this for you, there is no default `admin.py` generated.

To create one, if you are following the tutorial - simply keep reading and in [part two](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial02/) you'll create the `admin.py` file when you learn about the admin contrib app and how to integrate it with your custom models.